# Is a recursive function an effective way to add table rows dynamically?

Tags: javascript, recursion, dynamic, html-table, rows

In my research and attempts to use JavaScript to add rows to a HTML Table dynamically, it was important that each id tag be incremented according to the row number. I found various suggested ways of doing this. Finally, I thought I'd give a try at writing a recursive function to do the trick. The following works. But I do not know if it could be optimized. Kindly let me know what I can do to improve it.

```
function incrementElementID(element, incrementVal) {

if(element.hasAttribute("id")) {
    idVal = element.getAttribute("id");
    element.setAttribute("id",idVal+incrementVal);
}

var numChildren = element.childElementCount;
for (var i=0; i<numChildren; i++)
    incrementElementID(element.children[i],incrementVal);

return;

}
```

Comment: Why not to use `tr`s [`rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement.rowIndex) property to create an id, no need for an external function.

Answer (score 0):

Best done with a closure variable if you're not intentionally trying to use recursion.

Set a variable outside the function scope and increment it within the function.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off with some simple jQuery:

```
var incrementVal = ...
$("[id]").each(function(index, value) {
    elem = $(value);
    elem.attr("id", +elem.attr("id") + incrementVal);
});
```

`$("[id]")` selects any element that has an id attribute: http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/

`.each` iterates through all the items in the collection: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

The + at the front of `+elem.attr("id")` converts the attribute value from a string to an int.